How to trigger/start the movement of a ROS2 mobile robot from Gazebo?
I'm developing a ROS2 node that controls a mobile robot in Gazebo Harmonic. For simplicity sake, we can say that all the node does is sending commands to a robot so that it starts moving in circles.
As soon as the node starts executing, it registers a timer callback which will regularly send robot velocity commands. I want to change the behavior of the node so that it doesn't sends the commands immediately, and instead will wait for some kind of user input.
Based on my research, I think it's reasonable to create a ROS2 service that will start the robot movement when requested. So the flow would be like: 1. Spawn robot node. 2. Wait for service request. 3. When service is requested, the robot starts moving. Are there other common or recommended approaches to handle this situation?
If I go with the approach I described above, I would like to add a button to a Gazebo GUI plugin that's responsible for requesting the ROS2 service. I think the ideal solution would be to have the button call a Gazebo service, which is translated to the actual ROS2 service through ros_gz_bridge. However, it seems like this directionality (Gazebo to ROS2) is not supported by ros_gz_bridge. I tried to make it work and didn't have success, and only after I saw the following message on ros2 run ros_gz_bridge parameter_bridge -h: "It is only supported to expose Gazebo servces as ROS services, i.e. the ROS service will forward request to the Gazebo service and then forward the response back to the ROS client", which seems to confirm my claim that it's not possible.
A workaround for this would be to request the ROS2 service directly from the plugin, and that creates a dependency between the Gazebo plugin and the ROS2 version. Are there alternatives that don't create such dependency?
Edit: It seems that ros_gz_bridge has limitations that make it not appropriate for my use-case. This issue suggests that it does not currently support custom messages. This would rule out the usage of the bridge for a custom topic (unless modifying source code and building from source). The viable options seem to be either using built-in message types supported by the bridge, or publishing ROS2 topics directly.
